# Force overwrite of newer file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to stop being prompted about overwriting a newer file, and just allow the editor to overwrite it without asking?

I ask because I'm experiencing a bug in VS Code 1.9.0 that others are also experiencing which causes the editor to erroneously interpret a remote file as newer, hence forcing the user to view a diff and confirm the overwrite. This can happen several times in a row when I make small changes to a file, and it really disrupts my workflow.

The bug is known of by Microsoft and two reports of it exist on their Github, unfortunately both have been Closed without being resolved (or perhaps the bug was fixed in an earlier version but recently reintroduced), so I'm just looking for a temporary workaround for now until (hopefully) they fix it again.

For what it's worth, my platform is Debian Stable (8/Jessie) and I have a remote server mounted via sshfs (facilitated through PCManFM).

Answer (score 6):

Check out this setting:

Files: Save Conflict Resolution
A save conflict can occur when a file is saved to disk that was changed by another program in the meantime. To prevent data loss, the user is asked to compare the changes in the editor with the version on disk. This setting should only be changed if you frequently encounter save conflict errors and may result in data loss if used without caution.

[image: screenshot of setting]

Comment: I can't seem to find this setting in Preferences → Settings, could you point to a guide? What is your VSCode version?

Comment: The current version as of this comment is 1.57.0. It should be under Settings->Text Editor->Files